# Dropzone FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, dropzone.js

Dear friends I am currently creating an admin panel for user where they can easily can publish their articles. I also want to add to my form a little fileuploader but sadly I got some problems with DROPZONEJS.JS file in POST method. The main problem is I cannot give URL to project's local file in order to download to file there where website will access those file in order to publish them with current article's id. Please let me know if there is something not understandable.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Uppy";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
    <div class="content d-flex flex-column flex-column-fluid" id="kt_content">
        <!--begin::Entry-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-column-fluid">
            <!--begin::Container-->
            <div class="container">
                <!--begin::Card-->
                <div class="card card-custom gutter-b">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-label">File Upload</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--begin::Form-->
                    <form>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-lg-right">Multiple File Upload</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-primary" id="kt_dropzone_2">
                                        <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick">
                                            <h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                                            <span class="dropzone-msg-desc">Upload up to 10 files</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-lg-right">File Type Validation</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-success" id="kt_dropzone_3">
                                        <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick">
                                            <h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                                            <span class="dropzone-msg-desc">Only image, pdf and psd files are allowed for upload</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Uppy",
                            "FileUpload",
                            FormMethod.Post,
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) //multipart/form-data gives functionlity to inputes (search at web);
                        {
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-light-primary mr-2" />
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          }
                        </form>
                    <!--end::Form-->
                </div>
                <!--end::Card-->
                <!--end::Row-->
            </div>
            <!--end::Container-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Entry-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Content-->
```

By the way my own upload code is working correctly and also sends choosen file to url location where I wrote in controller.

```
    <label for="file">Upload File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn-hover-bg-success" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
    <br>
    <br>
    @ViewBag.Message
```

This is my FileUploadController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Uppy(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        ADAPTIVE_TESTEntities ent = new ADAPTIVE_TESTEntities();
        Adaptive.News.Models.NEWS news = new Adaptive.News.Models.NEWS();
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                news.PICTUREPATH = path;
                ent.NEWS.Add(news);
                ent.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Where in the `<input type='file'>` for the file upload control.

Answer (score 1):

it is not obvious to me, what and where really your problem is. What do you mean with having problem. Is your problem with Dropzone.JS or with C#? Anyway, I examined your code slightly and have some ideas what your problem could be.

FIRST OF ALL: You have 2 DIV containers, which you use as Dropzone elements assigning them the css class "dropzone". Furthermore you generate a FORM element with ASP.Net HTML-Helper.

By default you have 2 options using Dropzone.

1. Declarative instantiation via assigning css class "dropzone" to any HTML element.
   Dropzone discovers all DOM elements with class="dropzone" automatically and instantiates them.
2. Programmatically instantiating: You instantiate Dropzone by passing the id of the container element and THE OPTIONS CONTAINING POST URL to the Dropzone constructor.

**DECLARATIVE DROPZONE**

You must pay attention to this detail: If you use FORM element as Dropzone container element, Dropzone uses "action" attribute of the FORM element as post URL. But if you use
DIV element as container, then you get most possibly a JavaScript error. Because DIV elements do usually NOT have "action" attribute. If you use DIV as Dropzone container (and in your code you use it 2 times), you will get following JavaScript error:

```
dropzone.js:1027 Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
    at new Dropzone (dropzone.js:1027)
    at dropzone.js:2907
    at Function.Dropzone.discover (dropzone.js:2919)
    at Dropzone._autoDiscoverFunction (dropzone.js:3491)
    at HTMLDocument.init (dropzone.js:3456)
```

In this case you have two options solve the problem:

1. Use FORM element instead of DIV as Dropzone container.
2. Add action="/your/post/url" to your DIV element, which you use as Dropzone container.

Where I would prefer the first option. Because it is not common that DIV elements have action attribute.